# send data from parent window to child window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well I have Search for few question in StackOverFlow but not matching with my requirement.
What I am trying to achieve is, user will enter the details in the parent window on click of login button the data username and password will be send to the child window and the same time parent data should be removed, child window will be opened using window.open.... as of now I am just trying to show an alert in child window.
I will not able to use here ajax due to some reason.

**here is my code**

**HTML**

```
<form class="modal-content animate">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        <img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <label><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="userName" id="userName" required>

        <label><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="password" required>

        <button type="button" id="loginBtn">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
    $("#loginBtn").click(function () {
        var newWindow = window.open("http://127.0.0.1:64449/page10.html", "status=1", "toolbar=0", "location=0");
        newWindow.userName = $("#userName").val();
        newWindow.passWord = $("#passWord").val();
        return newWindow;
        //alert should come in child popup
        alert(window.userName + " " + window.passWord);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Where's your code in the child window to do the `alert`?

Comment: Two notes: 1. You need to wait for the window to load (at least partially) before assigning those variables, and 2. It's not best practice to store passwords in plaintext in variables if you can avoid it.

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Send-value-from-Parent-page-window-to-Child-popup-window-using-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - that will be encrypted in future as off now I am just trying the plain text,    alert(window.userName + " " + window.passWord); :)

Comment: @UrvishPatel is there any possiblity to close the parent window after getting the data!

Comment: @Aryan I dont think that you can reach or get the data after close the window but if you want that you need this data after close parents :- [window.locationstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)  use it.

Comment: try: `$(newWindow.document.body).find('#userName').val($("#userName").val());`